# Cron job to run a script at the begining of the month

Tags: cron

I would like to write a cron job that has to run a PHP script on the 1st day of each month.

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to *crontab -e* this:

```
0 0 1 * * php /path/to/script.php
```

Good luck!